# VB.Net Beginner: Replace with Wildcards, Possibly RegEx?

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, wildcard

I'm converting a text file to a Tab-Delimited text file, and ran into a bit of a snag. I can get everything I need to work the way I want except for one small part.

One field I'm working with has the home addresses of the subjects as a single entry ("1234 Happy Lane Somewhere, St 12345") and I need each broken down by Street(Tab)City(Tab)State(Tab)Zip. The one part I'm hung up on is the Tab between the State and the Zip.

I've been using input=input.Replace throughout, and it's worked well so far, but I can't think of how to untangle this one. The wildcards I'm used to don't seem to be working, I can't replace ("?? #####") with ("??" + ControlChars.Tab + "#####")...which I honestly didn't expect to work, but it's the only idea on the matter I had.

I've read a bit about using Regex, but have no experience with it, and it seems a bit...overwhelming.

Is Regex my best option for this? If not, are there any other suggestions on solutions I may have missed?

Thanks for your time. :)

EDIT: Here's what I'm using so far. It makes some edits to the line in question, taking care of spaces, commas, and other text I don't need, but I've got nothing for the State/Zip situation; I've a bad habit of wiping something if it doesn't work, but I'll append the last thing I used to the very end, if that'll help.

```
If input Like "Guar*###/###-####" Then
input = input.Replace("Guar:", "")
input = input.Replace("  ", ControlChars.Tab)
input = input.Replace(",", ControlChars.Tab)
input = "C" + ControlChars.Tab + strAccount + ControlChars.Tab + input
End If

input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(" #####", ControlChars.Tab + "#####") <-- Just one example of something that doesn't work.
```

This is what's written to input in this example

```
"         Guar: LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME  999 E 99TH ST  CITY,ST 99999  Tel: 999/999-9999"
```

And this is what I can get as a result so far

```
C   99999/9  LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME   999 E 99TH ST   CITY    ST 99999    999/999-9999
```

With everything being exactly what I need besides the "ST 99999" bit (with actual data obviously omitted for privacy and professional whatnots).

UPDATE: Just when I thought it was all squared away, I've got another snag. The raw data gives me this.

```
#   TERMINOLOGY #########   ##/##/####  #   ###.##
```

And the end result is giving me this, because this is a chunk of data that was just fine as-is...before I removed the Tabs. Now I need a way to replace them after they've been removed, or to omit this small group of code from a document-wide Tab genocide I initiate the code with.

```
#TERMINOLOGY###########/##/########.##
```

Would a variant on rgx.Replace work best here? Or can I copy the code to a variable, remove Tabs from the document, then insert the variable without losing the tabs?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the code you've written so far. Yes, regex sounds like the tool for this job, but if you provide an example, someone can easily give you the line you need. (Plus, we like to see effort.)

Comment: Oh. Sure. I don't have a lot of faith in my code most of the time, though. Chalk it up to a constant feeling of being in over my head. I'll edit some into the original post..

Comment: The state and zip are all different throughout the document, though. That's one thing that's got me hung up on understanding an application of Regex.Replace.

Comment: Can you add some example input too?

Comment: Do the tabs represent a field separator? If so, how do you know where to put them so that all the fields are consistant?

Comment: They do. In this case I got lucky because any field that needed a Tab already had two spaces between it, with the exception of the gap between State and Zip. With this field and one other on the project being the only two without established entry lengths, it was a bit of a bother (moreso for the other one than this one), but this part of it is the only one I really got hung up on.

Comment: So what you're saying is the result of the current replacements is `"\t\t\t\t\tLASTNAME\tFIRSTNAME\t999 E 99TH ST\tCITY\tST 99999\tTel: 999/999-9999"` ?

Comment: Not exactly. The first comment to @acheong87 answering below explains it. It only put the \t into where I needed the last Tab left to go, and that was only due to a little code hiccup that was fixed. Everything's shiny now.

Comment: Wasn't the point. Pretend the `\t` literal in my string is a tab. Wondering if all those "leading tabs" are part of the result of you're original replacements, and if thats a consistent reflection of blank fields relative to all lines in the text.

Comment: No. It didn't copy precisely, but each entry has a certain number of tabs between them reflecting a number of blank entries between them. In the case of the addresses we're dealing with, everything is separated by only one tab, each. The initial entry (the one with "Tel:" still in it) is littered with spaces. These are all removed and replace with a single Tab per data field.

I hope that clears this up. Sorry if I'm a bit unclear on anything here. I'm still getting the hang of...explaining things well.

Comment: @Eiketsu - Hey thanks. No, it didn't clear it up. But, I can imagine machine generated fixed field delimeters (double space), however, that requires changing all data text from double-space -> single-space to avoid delimiter conflict. Something about that would seem to me a little problamatic. Good Luck with it!

Comment: I was going to tell you this before. You should do all of the replacement with a _single_ regex. It avoids the problems you now encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(" (\d{5})(?!\d)")
Dim input As String = rgx.Replace(input, ControlChars.Tab + "$1")
```

The first line *compiles* the regular expression. The `\d` matches a digit, and the `{5}`, as you can guess, matches 5 repetitions of the previous atom. The parentheses surrounding the `\d{5}` is known as a *capture group*, and is responsible for putting what's captured in a pseudovariable named `$1`. The `(?!\d)` is a more advanced concept known as a *negative lookahead assertion*, and it basically peeks at the next character to check that it's not a digit (because then it could be a 6-or-more digit number, where the first 5 happened to get matched). Another version is

```
" (\d{5})\b"
```

where the `\b` is a *word boundary*, disallowing alphanumeric characters following the digits.

Comment: Well, it found the correct location in the entry, but input the \t, like this.

    C   99999/9  LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME   999 E 99TH ST   CITY    ST\t99999 999/999-9999

Is there a different syntax to be used for a Tab? Because other than that (an my barely following it - though thank you for the solid explanation!), it seems to have done exactly what I was after.

Comment: @Eiketsu - Oh, my bad. I forgot this was VB.NET. Let me edit. Okay, now try.

Comment: And your explanation really helps me follow along with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx, so thank you for that, too.

Comment: Excellent! That nailed it. But...nuts. I'm not high enough rep for an upvote. Well...doesn't change the fact you're the hero of the day. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hrm. Any advice for the Updated trouble I hit?